# $scope.$apply returns a circular error after loading data into a angular-ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ui-grid

An example:
The code is triggered by this HTML:

```
<div google-chart chart = "chartObject" style = "height:600px; width:100%;" agc-on-select="selectHandler(selectedItem)" ng-if="chartvisible"></div>
```

This Creates a UI grid:

```
$scope.gridOptions = gridService.getGrid([25, 50, 75], 25, ['username','startTime']);
 

    $scope.gridOptions.data = post;
     $scope.$apply();
```

Where the variable 'Post' is something like:

```
[
   {
       "challenge": "asdfrew2",
       "id": 1,
       "startTime": "start time 1",
       "successfullyCompleted": false,
       "username": "JamieFalter"
   },
   {
       "challenge": "454454y",
       "id": 2,
       "startTime": "start time 2",
       "successfullyCompleted": false,
       "username": "Falter"
   }
]
```

Returns an error that looks like this:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>
> ```
> at na (angular.js:1121)
> at angular.js:20566
> at Object.fn (angular.js:12411)
> at k.$digest (angular.js:12540)
> at k.$apply (angular.js:12805)
> at Object.<anonymous> (Controller.js:54)//Points to the Scope.Apply
> at i (jquery.min.js:2)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
> at y (jquery.min.js:4)
> at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)
> ```

Has anyone seen anything like this before?  If so, how did you solve it?

Comment: Can you provide additional code? And why are you manually calling `$apply()`? Did you execute some function that was outside of angulars context?

Comment: What additional code would you like to see?

Comment: I thought scope.apply was used to automatically force a page update.  Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: What is triggering that snippet of code to execute? Any time some angular event occurs such as an `ng-click`, `$http` request, etc, the digest cycle kicks in starts doing the dirty checking and updating the views. If you're using vanilla angular, there *shouldn't* be much need for manually calling $apply.

Comment: I added the html that starts everything going.  It's all triggered by clicking on a node in a google graph. (the agc-on-select)